Using Fetch API GET request, receiving response (HTML code) and reloading whole web page (not only parts) with that code
Let us say we are sending a Fetch API Get request to the server.
The server response with text, in specific with the whole new webpage in html code.
How do I get the browser refresh the page with this html?
Sure there is the way for replacing snippets in page like in div containers. But how to refresh the whole page with below shown html code?
<!-- html code sent by server -->
<html>
<header>
   <title>animals</title>
</header>
<body>
 <p>A spider is an animal.</p>
</body>

//Client side
fetch('/animals')
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then(value => /*Iam missing this step*/)


I've done similar with DOMParser and parseFromString(), which turns a string into html. Then you can use the usual DOM methods to grab pieces of your returned html and append, replace, whatever in the original DOM.

Many thanks for your answers and time, document.write() does the job!

Be careful using document.write to replace the content of a page after it has loaded: Google destroyed its usefulness for this by not resetting the global environment to its original state when writing to a closed document. As a result you can get errors trying to redefine global const and let variables in the new page that were defined in the old page. In other words, don't do it :-)

I like to use DOMParser to turn text into html, which can then be accessed via the usual DOM methods.


function replaceDivWithUpdatedVersion(ajaxResponse,targetDivID) {
    try {

        const parser = new DOMParser();
        const htmlString = ajaxResponse;
        const updatedHTML = parser.parseFromString(htmlString,"text/html");
        // debugger;
        if(updatedHTML.querySelector("cf-error")) {
            document.getElementById('alert_div').appendChild(createErrorMessage("Error re-rendering screen!"));
            return;
        }
        const div_to_replace = document.getElementById(targetDivID);
        const div_to_replace_with = updatedHTML.getElementById(targetDivID);
        // debugger;
        div_to_replace.parentNode.replaceChild(div_to_replace_with,div_to_replace);
    }
    catch(err) {
        console.error(err);
        console.log("ajaxResponse",ajaxResponse);
        console.log("targetDivID",targetDivID);
        console.groupEnd();
    }
}
document.getElementById("btnUpdate").addEventListener("click",()=>replaceDivWithUpdatedVersion('<div id="updateThis">new div that was updated</div>',"updateThis"));
<div id="updateThis">
  div to update
</div>
<div id="keepThis">
  constant div that won't change
</div>
<button type="button" id="btnUpdate">
update the first div
</button>



